# Sharing data beetwen scripts in a Jenkins job

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I'll describe the problem briefly:

1. there's a Jenkins job
2. script1 calculates foo
3. many different scripts are doing their job
4. script2 needs to do something with the foo value that was calculated by the script1

The question is - how to send the foo? Writing to a file? Maybe environmental variable?

What would be the best approach - or maybe this whole idea is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need to use an envrionment variable, All you need to return value from `scriptA.sh`  and pass the return value as an argument to `scriptB.sh`

Suppose, Script A calculate total file in the directory and return total file

**ScriptA.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
total_file=$(ls -1q | wc -l)
echo "${total_file}"
```

**ScriptB.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
foo_from_scriptA="${1}"
echo "Got Foo from script ScriptA.sh that is $foo_from_scriptA"
```

Configure Both scripts in your Execute Shell of Jenkins. Keep both script in the root directory of your Job folder in workspace.

```
cd $WORKSPACE
foo=$(./scriptA.sh)
echo "passing foo to scriptB"
./scriptB.sh $foo
```

[image]

You will see the logs in the console that foo is consumed by `scriptB.sh`

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! I haven't thought about it, thank you so much 

Comment: you Welcome dear @PawełRubin, enjoy scripting ;) :)